# Tab completion with custom __dir__ does not work with IPython 7.5

Tags: python, ipython, tab-completion

I upgraded to IPython 7.5.0 and now autocompletion of dynamic properties (i.e. overriding `getattr`) of a class no longer work.

For instance:

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.d = None
    def c(self): pass
    def __dir__(self):
        return ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
f = Foo()
f.<tab>
```

Completes only `c()` and `d`. The IPython docs say that overriding dir is all that's necessary [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/integrating.html), and it seemed to work previously.

I'm on Windows 10, Python 3.6.4, IPython 7.5.0, Jupyter 1.0, Jupyter-Console 5.2.

Comment: Solved it by upgrading from jedi 0.11 to 0.13